# Data truncation and null input strings

Tags: talend

I am working in Talend and have managed to get data from a CSV file and filter it before putting into a table. The problem I am having now is to do with the length of the data.

This is the red text I get:

```
For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Street' at row 58
For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Street' at row 23 
...
```

etc.

I have changed the length of the data in my schema such that it is propagated everywhere. I really don't know what to do to resolve this.

Comment: What's the data length for the column in the database table? This looks more like a DB error than a Talend error.

Comment: I've made them all 50 then I made them 100 then I made them all 10. Haha. doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Ohhh in the actual database... yeah I'm with u now. doing that.

Comment: Awesome. The data truncation issue is resolved. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Any ideas about the "null" input strings?

Comment: Are your columns not nullable in the database while having null strings in Talend? If you can post your DDL for your table and the data you're pushing (and even a screenshot of the job) that might help.

Comment: what is nullable property for schema in talend file component you are using? Could you post some sample rows from  your csv.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed above, this problem is caused because the output data is longer than the maximum defined length in the database's table. Check the definition and alter it if possible.

Other solution is to output a short version of the data using an expresion like row1.column.substring(0,50) in the output flow.